# wxPython wxListBox Contains

Tags: python, wxpython

Does [wxListBox](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListBox.html) have the equivalent of C# `ListBox.Items.Contains()`? I looked into `FindString()` but I don't think that's it, or I'm not using `FindString()` right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
# self.reviece_list is a Listbox. 
self.reviece_list.FindString(self.combo.GetStringSelection()) == wx.NOT_FOUND:
```